# Qml Image mipmap

Tags: android, image, qt, qml, mipmaps

Im currently working with QML and android and I'm trying to add a multi-sized image as a resource (`.qrc`) and load it using `Image`. I found that `Image` has a property called `mipmap` to realize that, but I don't understand how to use it. I tried it with a `.ico` file - without success. Any suggestions how to do this? I wasn't able to find anything about it.

Here my code - although it's very simple:

```
Image {
    id: btnImg
    source: "qrc:/icons/btnImg.png"  //Tried an multi-sized .ico file
    mipmap: true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mipmap is used to have better visual quality, but it says nothing about multi-sized images. Probably you need to implement a custom Image component for what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Mipmap filtering gives better visual quality when scaling down.

I think QML Image's source is switchable when the image size is large.

```
Image {
    id: btnImg
    // if width is larger than 500, use the large scale image
    source: width > 500 ? "largeBtnImg.png" : "smallBtnImg.png"
    mipmap: true
    ...
}
```